# how can I show the information of a list object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have books categorized by the category attribute, how can I get the description value of the books to display on a screen?

already tried using values ​​() and the keys ()

```
{1: Array(2), 2: Array(1), 4: Array(1), 9: Array(1)}

1: Array(2)
0: {id: 1, description: "teste", category: 1}
1: {id: 73, description: "basica tb", category: 1}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
2: Array(1)
0: {id: 3, description: "Teoria das ideias", category: 2}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
4: Array(1)
0: {id: 5, description: "Mr with research computer.", category: 4}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
9: Array(1)
0: {id: 10, description: "Vote drug thus no.", category: 9}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

i need return the title of objects bibliographies

Comment: Can you please give the real data instead of copying it from console.

Comment: the data is returned by an api, I am using the react and I have a state that receives this data, I am using the groupby function to group them by categories, now I need to show for example:
Category 1
description1
description2

Category 2
description2
.
.
.
.

Comment: Why is your question tagged with Python?

Comment: Sorry, I put it wrong.

Comment: @GustavoNogueira can you give an example of your expected output?

Comment: @Kobe for example, category1[description 1, description 2], category2[description3, description5]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work. Use `Object.keys` and `reduce`, to `map` over every value and return the description:

```js
const data = {
    1: [
        {id: 1, description: "teste", category: 1},
        {id: 73, description: "basica tb", category: 1}
    ],
    2: [
        {id: 3, description: "Teoria das ideias", category: 2}
    ],
    4: [
        {id: 5, description: "Mr with research computer.", category: 4}
    ],
    9: [
        {id: 10, description: "Vote drug thus no.", category: 9}
    ]
}

const getDescription = data => Object.keys(data).reduce((a, key) => ({...a, [key]: data[key].map(o => o.description)}), {})

console.log(getDescription(data))
```

Comment: sorry but when I try to show on the screen the results I get this error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Answer (score -1):

Hi Gustavo I'm not quite sure what you want but i think you want to render a list of your object. There are so many ways to do it but im going to show you the most easy way by using javascript higher-order function `map`.This higher-order function let's you to loop through your array.

***Simple Instance:***

```
import React from 'react';

const List = () => {
      const data = [{
      name: 'Joe',
      age: '16'
      }]
      return (
      {data.map(data => <li key={data.age}>{data.name}</li>)}
)
}
```

Comment: You cannot map an object

Comment: Also, `data.Joe` will return undefined, you are looking for `data.name`

Comment: @GustavoNogueira They have edited their code now 